# How to generate random number with out duplicates using JSON array in android

Tags: android, json, random

I am new to android. I am doing quize app.I have one JSON array text file.how to generate random number with out repetation using JSON array in android..please help me
Thank you adv.. 
this is my sample code

```
public static JSONArray getQuesList()throws JSONException{

     ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(size);
        for(i =size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            //index = rnd.nextInt(list.size());
            list.add(i);
        }

        Random rand = new Random();
        while(list.size() > 0) {
            index = rand.nextInt(list.size());
            Object object = quesList.get(index);
              quesList.put(index, quesList.get(i));
              quesList.put(i, object);
            Log.d("","Selected: "+list.remove(index));
        }
        return quesList;
```

Comment: Why not load the `rnd.nextInt(i + 1)` in an array of integers and then in a sub-loop check if the newly generated one exists in it? If yes, then generate a new one, if no - use the current.

Comment: swap already random why ask? I change my answer. Try it. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

[QuestionActivity.java](https://github.com/gitssk/quizfun/blob/master/src/ssk/quizfun/QuestionActivity.java)

Global variable

```
int[] quizarray = null;
```

Add two functions

```
private void createQuizIndex() {
    int[] array = new int[QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().length()];
    quizarray = new int[QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().length()];

    for(int i = 0 ; i < QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().length() ; i++){
        array[i] = i;
    }

    Random random = new Random();
    int m = 0;
    for (int n = array.length ; n > 0; n--){    
        int r = random.nextInt(n);
        quizarray[m++] = array[r];
        array[r] = array[n-1];  
    }
}

private int getIndexNum(int quesIndex2) {
    return quizarray[quesIndex2];
}
```

Change every **showQuestion**

```
showQuestion(getIndexNum(quesIndex),review);
```

Call **createQuizIndex()** in line 80, and line 194 if "Retake" means another random quiz